# How to select only alternate (or even/odd) elements of only certain types?

Tags: css

say this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>ciao</div>
  <p>ciao</p>
  <span>ciao</span>
  <div>ciao</div>
  <div>ciao</div>
  <span>ciao</span>
  <i>ciao</i>
  <p>ciao</p>
  <div>ciao</div>
</div>
```

Now, is there any way to select only even elements, out of a list composed by `div` and `p`, excluding all the other types?

I mean:

```
.container > *:nth-child(even){ // >>> BUT only from say, P and DIV
  color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only partly: `:nth-child` (of any kind) counts *all*  child elements at the same level inside the same parent, regardless of their type.

There is `nth-of-type`, which comes closer to what you want:

```css
p:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>p / 1</p>
  <h2>h2 / 2</h2>
  <p>p / 3</p>
  <p>p / 4</p>
  <div>div / 5</div>
  <p>p / 6</p>
</div>
```

But this isn't possible with *two*  tag types, only with *one*, like in the example above.

Comment: @TemaniAfif true, I changed my answer. However, it's not possible to apply nth-of-type in the way the OP asked for, i.e. for two different tag types.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You will need to do it via Javascript:

```
var items = document.querySelector(".container").querySelectorAll("div, p");
for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if (!(index % 2)) {
        items[index].style.color = "red";
    }
}
```